# Display two div (one Highstock chart and one table) inline in an bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to place two divs (One is Highstock, and another one is an simple table) side by side 
in an wrapper div in an bootstrap3 modal.

But no matter what I tried, the table would show on the next line.

I had set the inline-block property, and wrap the highstock chart in an div.

Could some one give me an hint? Many thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/t2NcN/3/embedded/result/

```
.modal-dialog{
   width:90%;    
}
#wrap{    
   width:100%;
}
#left_div{
   width:70%;
   display:inline-block;
}
#right_div{
    width:30%;
    display:inline-block;    
}
```